# Different max width to different pages in Ionic 4

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am using Ionic 4 to build a small web app. I use the following on `global.scss` to limit the page width, so it will have a similar look on both desktop and mobile:

```
.ion-page {
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

This trick works as advertised, but I want to override this rule **for one page only** so it will appear on full width.

How can I set custom max width per page in Ionic 4?

Comment: not an Ionic developer but do you have separate scss files for each component, like Angular? If yes, you can use `:host{max-width:100%}` within the scss file

Comment: @SagarV Chrome's dev tools show that the host property overrides the global default, but since the top-level container has a `ion-page` class also, it is still rendered with 700px max width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go the .scss of that page you want to customize.
First open your ts file and update your component metadata to

```
@Component{
    selector: 'your-page-selector',
    templateUrl: 'your-page-selector.html',
    styleUrls: ['your-page-selector.scss'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
}
```

the ViewEncapsulation is part of '@angular/core';

Now go to your your-page-selector.scss and add this:

```
your-page-selector {
  // apply your custome css here
}
```

This will actually remove Dom shadowing to this component allowing you to apply all the CSS you want to that specific page/component

[To read more on ViewEncapsulation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation)

Comment: This has been the root of the problem! Angular view encapsulation settings affect the way each page can override Ionic's settings, since pages are children of the Ionic app component.

Comment: Yes, Ionic 4 and its Dom shadowing is pain. It took me a month to migrate one app from ionic3 to 4 just because of Dom shadowing and other unnecessary changes they have made like ion-button, and size="xx" instead of col-xx etc etc.